# Help with translation, please!

Tags: translation

I have two small japanese paintings with words on them.

Can anyone help me with translation? Thank you so much.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The left image should be turned over. It reads 細香寫. 細 means slender, fine, thin. 香 means fragrance, perfume. 寫 or 写 means copy, write, photo. In all, I can't decipher its meaning.
The right image is not turned over. Its upper character reads 耕 cultivate. Its lower character I can't read.

Comment: could it be a version of 園?

Comment: It might also be a seal script-y version of 安 in a box, though the line under the roof is odd.